# C++ - Create dialog box containing buttons and static text on click

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui, windows-controls

so this project follows my last question. I implemented the buttons and found out how to render events when they are clicked, this question is a next-step for me that I am struggling with. Utilizing the winapi I want to create a dialog box when a button is clicked on the window class, but I want the dialog box to take the properties of another window class so I can pass specific properties to it. How would I approach this? Again, some demo code would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time.